# git удаленный и локальный через VS code

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, git-pull

Не могу понять в чем дело. Работаю с github с нескольких устройств. В гите есть несколько веток, они одновременно синхронизированы на всех устройствах. На одном из устройств я ветку WordDB мерджу с main и удаляю её локально и удаленно, проверяю командой git branch -r, этой ветки нет ни локально ни удаленно. Захожу с другого устройства, запускаю vs code, захожу на ветку main, забираю все изменения, удаляю локальную ветку WordDB. Но при этом показывает что есть эта удаленная ветка, пытаюсь перейти на её через браузер, выдает ошибку что такой страницы не существует. Почему оттображаются удаленные ветки, которые я ранее удалил и которые не отображаются в web версии github?
Скриншоты ниже предлагаю.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Хотя команды тут не приведены, хрустальный шар показывает, что при получении обновлений на второй машине при выполнении `git fetch` не использовался флажек `--prune`, подчищающий локальные ссылки, которым больше нет соответствий в удаленном репозитории. Соответственно `origin/WordDB` там продолжает ссылаться туда же, куда и раньше.

Comment: Спасибо большое команда git fetch --prune решила эту проблему. Только не пойму за что минусанули мой вопрос, я ведь все максимально расписал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Необходимо в терминале выполнить команду `git fetch --prune`